# Does not name a type

Tags: c++, sfml

Есть вот такой код(работаю в Code Blocks):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Test
{
    sf::Texture testTexture;
    testTexture.loadFromFile("sheet1.png");
};
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
    }

return 0;
}
```

Это обычный код для проверки работоспособности sfml, взятый с их сайта. Я добавил к нему свой класс Test. При компиляции code blocks выдает такую ошибку:

```
main.cpp|6|error: 'testTexture' does not name a type
```

С чем это может быть связано и в какую сторону копать? Уже третий день бьюсь с этой ошибкой

P.S. без класса код отлично компилируется и работает

Comment: Настоятельно советую прочитать, что нибудь [такое](https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-classes/)  про классы. Пока у вас нет преедставления как они работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А какого поведения вы ожидаете от своего кода? Что по вашему должна делать строка

```
 testTexture.loadFromFile("sheet1.png");
```

внутри класса?

---

На самом деле то, что вы хотите делается с помощью [конструктора](http://cppstudio.com/post/6964/). Как-то так. Конструктор будет вызываться при создании объекта этого класса.

```
class Test
{
    sf::Texture testTexture;
    Test() {
        testTexture.loadFromFile("sheet1.png");
    }
};
```